# how can we model the behaviors of different types of users in DDD?

Tags: domain-driven-design, domain-model

I am in a situation in which I am supposed to model (in domain) requirement where a **user** can be **bill admin** and **system admin** and **employee**.

All the Admins can do whatever the normal user can do, but a normal user cannot do what the other roles can do. The problem is that I dont understand how I can do this *by inheriting the user entity* and I have read thats not a good idea, so dont want to go that way..

The **Employee**, **System Admin** and **Bill Admin** are different roles of a user. Any suggestions?

**Update :**

*More Information:* Given that the **Employees BC** and **Billing BC** and **System BC** are three different Bounded Contexts what would be the ideal way of handling the above given scenario?

Comment: You haven't given much detail, but for me it seems those three roles are actually in three different bounded contexts ("bill", "system", and "employee" seem very unrelated to me), and thus you'd probably better of to model them completely independent, even if this means some code duplication.

Comment: yes, that is exactly the case, they do belong to different Business contexts and maybe my way of thinking is wrong, I am still thinking the data way.. i.e. the users table can be re used for all three roles by having a role id maybe i can reuse entities the same way which perhaps is wrong thinking in domain modeling..

Comment: The general recommendation is that you should avoid "reusing" of any form between BC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It may be that you are mixing bounded concepts and the inheritance is probably not helping either :)

Typically one would have an *Identity and Access Control* BC.  This is where we may find a `User`, `Permission`, and a `Role`.

Then one may have an *Employee* or *Human Resources* BC.  This is where concepts such as `Employee` and `Manager` may exist.

So it may help to split these concepts.

When a new employee is registered an `EmployeeRegistered` event may be published by the *HR* BC, using a service bus, that the *I & AC* BC subscribes to in order to register a new user.

Hope that helps.

Comment: hmm, that looks like a pretty neat solution but if i have three business contexts i.e. Bill, System, and Employee is the I & AC BC listening to the events published by these BC's the ideal way of modeling the given situation?

Comment: Having distinct BCs with an event-driven architecture may very well make your life easier.  Modelling can be tricky and your model in any given BC may need some re-thinking every-so-often but at some point one tends to find a good balance and something that feels comfortable.  Along the way it means changes to the messages are quite likely.  So given the fact that I am not a domain expert in your environment my hypothetical case may no be "ideal" but it is certainly a starting point :)